# how: mathematical induction prove inequation

Tags: induction

Provided that $p\geq-1$, prove $(1+p)^n\geq1+np$ for all integers $n\geq 0$

Also, where in the calculation do I use $p\geq -1$?

Thanks guy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base case, if $n = 0$, then $(1 + p)^0 = 1  \geq 1 $. So Equation trivially holds! No suppose it holds for $n$ in $Z^+$. Then
$$ (1+p)^{n+1} = (1+p)^n(1+p)  \geq (1+np)(1+p) = 1+np^2 + np + p  \geq 1 +(n+1)p. $$ 
The proof is concluded by math induction.

Comment: how did you come up with multiplying by 1+p on both sides? o-o its indeed a good trick

Comment: Thats what You want to proof. The $n+1$ case!

Comment: can i prove this without multiplying n+1 on both sides? and do i use this trick for all Induction problems?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: @LJym89 The term $n^2p$ should be $np^2$ (note that $n^2p$ could be negative).

Comment: Sorry, my bad ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you use this : $(1+p)^n \geq 1 + np$ then $(1+p)^n(1+p) \geq (1+np)(1+p)$ if $p < -1$ then the inequality reversed, that is your question, right ?