# Prove that $n! \geq 2^{n-1}$ for $ n\geq1$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

Mathematical Induction:-Prove that $n! \geq 2^{(n-1)}$ for $n\geq 1$.

I tried mathematical induction but could not

Comment: If you search this site a little, you will find several very similar questions, for example, [Proof the inequality $n! \geq 2^n$ by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/proof-the-inequality-n-geq-2n-by-induction) and
[Is this induction procedure correct? ($2^n<n!$)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245576/is-this-induction-procedure-correct-2nn).

Answer (score 2):

Base case: If n = 1, then $1 = 1! \geq 1 = 2^{1 - 1}$.

Induction step: Suppose that $n! \geq 2^{n - 1}$ for some $n \geq 1$; we must show that this holds if we replace $n$ by $n + 1$. Now we have $n + 1 \geq 2$, so

$$(n + 1)! = (n + 1) n! \geq 2 (n!) \geq 2(2^{n - 1}) = 2^{n} = 2^{(n + 1) - 1}$$

as desired. Note that the second inequality is where we use the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard. First we show that if $n=1$ the claim holds:
$$n! =1! =1 = 2^0 =2^{1-1}$$
Now *suppose* that there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so that your statement holds.
Then 
$$(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n! \geq (n+1) \cdot  2^{n-1}$$ The inequality above follows by your *induction hypothesis*. Now 
$$(n+1)! \geq n\cdot 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} \geq 1\cdot 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} =2\cdot 2^{n-1}=2^n$$
And this completes your proof. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$, clearly equality holds.

If $n \geq 2$, $n!=n(n-1)(n-2) \dots(2)(1)$ has the first $n-1$ factors $\geq2$, and the last factor $1$.